# using transcation with triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have this table in my database :

Reservation (num PK,  room number , reservation date)

I want before making a reservation, we check if the room is not taken using triggers.

this is the script I tried :

```
ALTER TRIGGER Verifier_chambre_prise ON reservation
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM reservation
                    WHERE [room number] = (SELECT [room number] FROM INSERTED)
                    AND [reservation date] = (SELECT [reservation date] FROM INSERTED))
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        ELSE
                        INSERT INTO reservation  SELECT * FROM INSERTED
    END
```

when I add a reservation that it is exists it gives me the error where the transaction has stopped the action, but the problem is that when I'm trying to add a row who has a  [reservation date] and a [room number] which is already exist in the table, this row is delted and I don't know why sql server delete this row .

Comment: Are you inserting the row in the same transaction?

Comment: If the only purpose of this trigger is to prevent insertion of duplicates, have you considered using a `unique constraint` based on the room and reservation date ?

Comment: @YanBrunet I cant use the UNIQUE constraint because the exercise I'm trying to do is like that, there is no constraint on [room number],[reservation date]

Comment: you are saying that this trigger somehow deletes a row from the table that existed before the insert? If so, could you post all your code (CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, INSERTs and anything else) or even better create a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) that demonstrates this?

Comment: I think : if you use insert command in trigger(`INSTEAD OF INSERT`) then insert command again call trigger... it will be something like recursive which never ended...